# Having an issue with conditional after getting strings lower

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am a noob in coding and still learning the basics. I've been messing with the code and I have reached this situation where the code is just broken. I want to make a simple conditional but lowering the input of the user to make sure the conditional works. I have asked Chat GPT, and two different "AI Code Checkers" and all these tools tell me that the code is just fine, and it looks like it. But obviously is not. Can anyone explain to me what is wrong?

```
while True:


    main_colors = ["cian", "amarillo", "magenta"]

    user_input = input("Introduce el color (en español): ")
    user_input_lower = user_input.lower

    if user_input_lower in main_colors:
        print("Es un color primario\n")


    else:
        print("No es un color primario\n")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your indentation is wrong, you also need to add the parens to the end of `user_input.lower()`

Comment: You have to actually *call* the `.lower()` method for it to do anything.  Currently, you're checking if the method itself is in the list...

Comment: user_put.lower == <built-in method lower of str object at 0x103d81370>

Comment: Then the solution is to add the parens. Thank you. I didn't know that :)

Comment: The reason 'code checkers' accepted the code is that it is syntactically valid even though it is useless. You have assigned `user_input_lower` to the method object  - but never called the method using `( )`. In some circumstances you might want to do such an assignment. Suggestion - don't rely on ChatGPT to write or correct code - it is does not understand the subtleties of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok now I understand much more! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your indentation is wrong you need to indent your whole code after the while condition, then you have to use the parenthesis after "lower" `user_input.lower()`. That was your only mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error in your code:
You have written: `user_input_lower = user_input.lower`
The correct syntax is `user_input_lower = user_input.lower()`

`lower()` is a method / function that you are performing on the `string:: user_input`. When you write `.lower` it is trying to look for a class variable lower in the class definition which does not exist and hence you get the error.